# What does "at%" refer to in sol-gel method?

Tags: terminology, photon-emission

I'm reading on the preparation of ZnO thin films for UV stimulated emission and I found a method called [Sol-Gel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sol-gel). During this I found a paragraph saying, " the ratio Ag/Zn in the sol is 3 at%......". so I want to know what at% refer to.

Comment: Atomic percent (vs weight percent).

Comment: more suitable for chemistry SE I think...